# Orchard ResourceManifest.cs - Searching in wrong location

Tags: css, resources, orchardcms, manifest

I have some problems with the ResourceManifest.cs of an Orchard custom module (let's call it 'testmodule'). In the manifest inside this testmodule I defined the following Style:

```
manifest.DefineStyle("Identifier123").SetUrl("dashboard.min.css");
```

that is located in the testmodule's Styles folder.

Now in the View (that is also located in the testmodule) I call:

```
Style.Require("Identifier123");
```

Unfortunately I get the following dashboard.min.css file added, instead of my file:

```
/Modules/Amba.ImagePowerTools/Styles/dashboard.min.css
```

When I rename my dashboard.min.css to dashboard2.min.css (and also in the manifest) it is working fine. Is this a normal behavior or some priority problem caused by Amba.ImagePowerTools? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What are your versions of OrchardCMS and ImagePowerTools?

Comment: Orchard 1.8.1 and ImagePowerTools (partially edited by our company) Module.txt:
Version: 2.3.2
OrchardVersion: 1.7. We just upgraded from 1.7 to 1.8.1 recently.

Comment: It's in your best interest to be as specific as possible in your file names, because of the way Orchard lets you override all kinds of files. "Dashboard.css" is as generic as it gets, and could only be beaten by "style.css". ;)

Comment: We use multiple modules, that have back- and frontend functionality. I wanted to create for each module a frontend.css and dashboard.css. Now I have to create each as i.e. 'Modulename'Dashboard.css ... Just wondering that the modules manifest does not search in its own style folder at first.